# Competitive SEO Vs Multiple Websites / Domains

Tags: seo, google, local-seo

We are a tour operator providing tours in a specific location within the UK.

Over the years we have focused on SEO on our site to ensure good Google rankings etc.
We have been optimising our site (keywords etc) and recently been link building to improve our domain rating.

Recently we have seen a number of our competitors launch multiple websites (different domains & looks and styling) which is having the effect of filling google search results with multiple hits/links to sites they control. ie. they get the booking regardless as to which "Company" / "Brand" the customer believe they have booked with.

Our question is from an SEO prospective should we continue work focusing on one domain/site or should we begin producing these micro sites?